# What is the difference between equation and formula?

Tags: terminology, definition

Sometimes equation and formula are used interchangeably, but I was wondering if there is a difference.

For example, suppose we can calculate a car's fuel efficiency as:

```
mpg = distance traveled in miles / the fuel used in a gallon
```

Is that an equation or formula?

Comment: According to http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/equation-formula.html, a formula shows a relationship between 2 or more variables, while an equation doesn't necessarily.

Comment: I was told by my guide that a very simple expression (for an unknown in terms of known) is better called an equation rather than a formula. I am noting this down here as I didn't see such a distinction based on the complexity of the expression in any of the answers.

Answer (score 43):

An *equation* is any expression with an equals sign, so your example is by definition an equation.  Equations appear frequently in mathematics because mathematicians love to use equal signs.

A *formula* is a set of instructions for creating a desired result.  Non-mathematical examples include such things as chemical formulas (two H and one O make H2O), or the formula for Coca-Cola (which is just a list of ingredients). You can argue that these examples are not equations, in the sense that hydrogen and oxygen are not "equal" to water, yet you can use them to make water.

Mathematicians have long since realized that when it comes to numbers, certain formulas can be expressed most succinctly as equations.  For example, the Pythagorean Theorem $a^2+b^2=c^2$ can be thought of as a *formula* for finding the length of the side of a right triangle, but it turns out that such a length is always *equal* to a combination of the other two lengths, so we can express the formula as an equation.  The key idea is that the equation captures not just the ingredients of the formula, but also the relationship between the different ingredients.

In your case, "mpg = distance/gallons" is best understood as "a formula in the form of an equation", which means that in this instance the two words are interchangeable.

Comment: There is also the technical meaning of "formula" as a well-formed arrangement of lexical pieces of a formal language, which I think is possibly more to the point here. In which case equations are a special case of formula.

Comment: Can you give an example of a formula without an equals sign?

Comment: So tl;dr formula = algorithm?

Answer (score 15):

An equation is meant to be solved, that is, there are some unknowns. A formula is meant to be evaluated, that is, you replace all variables in it with values and get the value of the formula.

Your example is a formula for `mpg`. But it can become an equation if `mpg` and one of the other value is given and the remaining value is sought.

Comment: So, is $y=3x+1$ the "formula for a line in the plane" or an equation for a line in the plane?

Comment: And if you treat a formula as an equation, solving for one variable to express in terms of other variables, then you have a new formula...

Comment: @Arturo, an equation, when both $x$ and $y$ are unknowns, but a formula for $y$ given $x$.

Comment: I fear this question is going to be closed because it's subjective and argumentative :-)

Comment: @lhf: Suffice it to say, I don't think I agree with your dichotomy.

Comment: @Arturo, not a clear-cut one, but I hoped it would help the OP. I may be wrong of course.

Comment: Better to ask this at the "english stack exchange". I think there are really sensical members there...

Comment: Well I pretty much agree with lhf. In german we have 2 words for a stretcher: Trage and Bahre. The difference is that the first one is used if the person that is located on it is alive and the second one is used when that person is already dead. So a Trage becomes a Bahre if that person dies. I guess it is pretty much the same with equations and formulas.

Comment: @Alexander, so a formula is like a dead equation? :-)

Comment: @lhf, that is probably the best comment on MSE.

Answer (score 6):

I'd say an equation is anything with an equals sign in it; a formula is an equation of the form $A={\rm\ stuff}$ where $A$ does not appear among the stuff on the right side.

Comment: I think the second one is a bit different. I think formula is an useful equation or kind of.

Comment: So isn't an inequality a formula?

Comment: @Leo, I'd say a formula has to be a formula for something, like $E=mc^2$ is a formula for energy, or $x=(-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac})/(2a)$ is a formula for the solutions of a quadratic equation. $\sqrt{ab}\le(a+b)/2$ isn't a formula for something.

Answer (score 5):

Please down vote me if you wish - but I would say these words are really synonyms to each other. They both express that there is some underlying relation between some mathematical expressions.

Comment: Synonyms? $ax^2+bx+c=0$ is a quadratic equation; $x={-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}\over2a}$ is the quadratic formula.

Comment: By your definition, Gerry, the quadratic equation is a formula for zero.

Comment: No downvote. I think that over time the distinction is lost. My math teacher, 35 years ago stated "formulas are used in chemistry, in math we have equations". To this day, the word 'formula' in math seems wrong, but I'd accept it's used commonly.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Thanks. Your teacher was right, but that does not exclude formulas in mathematics. I myself use both words.

Comment: @AD - The way he said it was a correction, and to say that the word 'formula' didn't belong in his (math) room. I'm old, but open to however something is used. To Gerry's point, the quadratic equation doesn't offer the solution, but the 'X=' has the solution, and I'd accept that as a distinction. If nothing else, his observation is clear to me if one really wanted two meanings for these two words.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I my opinion we can use both things as long as we understand each other.

Answer (score 3):

A formula is an equation that shows the relationship between two or more quantities.  It would be the rule or instructions that is used to show the relationship between two or more quantities.

An equation is a problem displayed with numerals or symbols with an equals ($=$) sign included somewhere; usually near the end of the equation.  Unless, it is a ratio or division.

Answer (score 2):

You solve an equation, while you evaluate a formula.

By the way, an equation that holds whatever the values of the variables is an identity.

Answer (score 1):

$e=mc^2$ and $f=ma$ are "equations", not normally called "formulas". You wouldn't say the "force formula", but the "force equation". They can have an infinite number of solutions. so i'd say the terms are interchangeable too.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer comes from https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/guides/zwbq6yc/revision/1

For your convenience a succinct explanation from the link is:

A **formula**:

1. shows the relationship between two or more variables (e.g. $\frac{9}{5}^{\circ}C + 32 =^{\circ}F$)
2. is a calculation for a specific purpose (e.g. the conversion from Celsius to Fahrenheit)
3. is always true, subject to certain conditions, no matter the inputs.

An **equation**:

1. will usually have only one variable, though it may appear more than once
2. will be correct only for certain values (e.g. $2x = 10$ is only true for $x = 5$)
3. is not always true.

Though I suggest you look at *expressions* and *identities* too.

Answer (score 1):

An **equation** is a statement that connects two expressions with an $=$ sign and asserts their equality.

An **identity** is an equation that holds for every variable tuple for which the equation is defined:

- $(x+y)^2\equiv x^2+y^2+2xy$

A **conditional equation** holds for some variable tuple(s):

- $x^2+ky^2=1\quad$ (the *parameter* $k$ is an arbitrary constant, varying to generate a family of equations)
- $2x^2+3x-5=0\quad$ (in the context of equation-solving, $x$ is an *unknown*)
- In a formula (the rule of a function) like $$V=\pi r^2h,$$ each input tuple returns an output called the subject.

An **inconsistent equation** holds for no variable tuple:

- $|2x|=x-1$

---

**Addendum**

A **constant** whose value is unspecified, a **parameter** and an **arbitrary constant** all mean the same, and each has a unspecified value (unless instantiated) in the context or problem. The first term emphasises the *placeholder*'s fixed value within the context (in contrast with a variable), the second term emphasises its varying value across contexts (in similarity with a variable), while the third term emphasises that its choice of value isn't important.

In the context of a constraint problem, a variable or a parameter or lettered constant can also be called an unknown.

Comment: Imagine that you were writing an elementary book, for example for high school learners, and at the beginning you had a glossary where you wanted to write the definitions for many mathematical words (e.g. numerical expression, algebraic expression, variable, equation, etc.) to help the reader make sense of those words when they appeared throughout the text. In this setting, what would you write to explain/define what a mathematical formula is? Imagine that you wanted to put an entry for formula in a table like this https://imgur.com/a/1hIc2Rd

Comment: Perhaps: A formula is a rule for expressing a subject in terms of some other variable(s); for example, $V=πr^2h$ expresses a cylinder's volume in terms of its radius and height.

Comment: Thanks! I opened a question on math educators, feel free to comment there.
https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/25351/definition-for-mathematical-formula

Answer (score 0):

An **equation** is a relationship that defines a restriction. for instance: $ area >= 2*depth*ratio $

In a **formula**, the equal sign actually means an assignment ($ \leftarrow  $): e.g. $ f(x,y) \leftarrow  x^2+y^2 $

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** I'd say it really depends on the context.

---

What I remember in high-school/secondary school:

We were given problems like

> Given length and area of a rectangle, find its width.

(Not exactly rectangle. that's of course more primary/grade school. Can be rectangular prism or whatever.)

The 'formula' is $A =wl$.

The 'equation' is what you get when you plug in the given values for $A$ and $l$. So if you have $A=10$ and $l=7$, then the equation is $10=7w$.

At the time, I thought it was very nit-picky/subjective/conventional/contextual. Now, I still do but I have the 10,000+ rep and bachelor's and master's degrees to complain about it.

According to my secondary school teachers, what you provided is a formula, but that's in the context of filling in the blanks of equation and formula in school.

**Conclusion**: I'd say it really depends on the context. If you define equation as a statement with an equal sign, then every formula with an equal sign is an equation... By the way, it seems on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula) that there are no inequalities that are formulas.

Answer (score 0):

In a formula all the variables can be arbitrarily chosen.
An equation  admits only particular values of non-constant variable/s.

Answer (score 0):

From various math books:

> An algebraic equation (or just equation) is a mathematical statement (or sentence) that relates 2 expressions with at least 1 variable.

Examples:

- $x = 10$.
- $y = 3x + 2$.

Counter-examples:

- $2 = 1 + 1$.
- $2 = 2$.

All expressions in those counter-examples are **arithmetic expressions**, they don't contain any variables. Those counter-examples are called arithmetic equations.

> A formula (or literal equation) is an equation involving 2 or more variables.

Examples:

- $y = x^{2} + 2$.
- $z = x^{2} + xy$.

Some authors (as in "W. Coburn, *College Algebra*, McGraw Hill", for example) stress the difference between a *literal equation* and a *formula* in which a literal equation is an equation involving 2 or more variables whereas a formula is a type of literal equation that  describes a known relationship between 2 or more variables. So, $ax + y = c$ is a literal equation but typically not formulas. However, $C=\frac{5}{9}(F-32)$ is indeed a formula to convert temperatures from Fahrenheit to Celsius.

Formulas can be written in functional notation, for example:

- $f(x)=x^{2} + 2$ instead of $y=x^{2} + 2$.
- $f(x, y)=x^{2} + xy$ instead of $z=x^{2} + xy$.

Answer (score -2):

One way to answer this question has been developed in the first and second courses of U.S. high school algebra.

In the fist course, the following definitions are formally stated in the glossary.

> **equation**: A statement formed by placing an equals sign between two numerical or variable expressions.

For example, $11-7=4$, $5x-1=9$, and $y+2=2+y$ are all equations because they all satisfy the given definition.

The following definition for a formula is also found formally stated in the glossary:

> **formula**: An equation that states a rule about a relationship.

Here are two useful formulas: $A=lw$, the formula for the area of a rectangle; $P=2l+2w$, the formula for the perimeter of a rectangle.

While at the beginning of the the second course, the following sentence summarizes that the relationship is between two or more variables:

> A **formula** is an equation that states a relationship between two or more variables.