# When do you make use of "≡" when verifying trigonometric identities?

Tags: trigonometry

My understanding is that I only use the symbol in lines where I make use of trigonometric identities.

Example: Prove $1+\tan^2x=\sec^2x$

$1+\tan^2x$

$≡1+\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}$ I make use of the triple bar here because I used a trig identity.

$=\frac{\cos^2x+\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}$ I only make use of the equal sign here since I didn't use any trig identities.

$≡\frac{1}{\cos^2x}$ I used the triple bar again because I used an identity.

$≡\sec^2x$

Is my understanding on its usage correct? Or should I be using the triple bar for all lines?

Comment: It has nothing to do with trigonometric identities, it has to do with other things

Comment: Yes, I get that. But say for example I'm using this sign when I'm verifying an identity. Am I actually using it right?

Comment: The standard use of $\equiv$ is completely different. None of the uses you propose are helpful or likely to be considered correct to the general mathematical reader.

Comment: This sign is used when something is identically equals to another thing (in your case, it is true for any $x\neq \pi/2+k\pi$.
I'd recommand to use $=$ and not $\equiv$, the latter being used in other fields of mathematics for particular purposes.

Comment: No, the tripple line equality sign is commonly used for either definition, this is the case because I define it so, or it has been defiend as such. Or because we're dealing with modulo.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols

Comment: Ohh okay. It's kinda confusing since I saw it like this in the math book I bought. I'll stick with the equals sign then.

Comment: Sometimes, in measure theory, I have seen $f\equiv g$ to mean $f(x)=g(x)\,\forall x$ and not only "almost everywhere".

Comment: i think triple lines mostly are used to represent coordinate points

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_bar#Mathematics_and_philosophy

Comment: @ArchisWelankar I see it mostly used (and translated into English) as "congruent", similarly how tilde-line-line (equals with tilde on top) is generally regarded as "congruent up to isomorphism".

Comment: Congruency got two double lines and one wavy line on top of two lines.@SubSevn

Comment: Refer to: [The different types of equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4254850/21813)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this context, I would recommend either:

1. don't use $\equiv$ at all, or
2. only use $\equiv$ to indicate implicit [universal quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification).

Let me explain what I mean by (2).

There's this concept of [universal quantification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_quantification) that all mathematics is based on. Its really important. If you understand it, math probably makes sense to you. If you don't, it probably doesn't. Unfortunately, this concept usually isn't taught until very late into one's university education, despite that essentially all of high school mathematics secretly uses it all the time! This makes mathematics look *way* crazier than it really is, which is a real shame.

So, let me try to explain it.

This will have the added benefit that you will know when to use $\equiv,$ in line with recommendation (2). Of course, you can always take recommendation (1) and just forget about $\equiv$ altogether... In any event, understanding this stuff is REALLY important.

**Universal quantification.**

Suppose we know that $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$.

Then obviously, we can deduce that $\sin^2(\theta+1)+\cos^2(\theta+1) = 1$.

(Think about *why.* This should be intuitively obvious. Don't read on until its obvious.)

Okay, suppose we instead know that $3x=2$. Can we deduce that $3(x+1) = 2$? Of course, we cannot. After all, the first statement is equivalent to $x=3/2$. The second statement is equivalent to $x=1/2$. Obviously, neither implies the other.

So what's really going on here?

Let me explain.

If someone says "we know that $3x=2$," then what they probably mean is exactly what they said. Basically, $x$ is understood to be some fixed but arbitrary real number, and we know that $3$ times that number equals $2$, or in other words that $3x=2$. We can then proceed to find $x$ (if we want).

But if someone says "we know that $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$," what they probably mean is: "we know that for each and every real number $\theta$, it holds that $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$." Obviously, we cannot proceed to find $\theta$ in this case, because we're talking about each and every possible $\theta$, not some specific $\theta$.

So *if* we want to be precise, *if* we want to denote things in a way that makes this difference in meanings clear, then obviously, we have to change our notation a bit.

The statement: "We know $3x=2$" remains unchanged.

But the other statement becomes: We know $$\mathop{\forall}_{\theta:\mathbb{R}}(\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2\theta = 1).$$

Let me explain how to read this. The symbol $\forall$ is verbalized "for all," or "for each," or "for every." A bit of terminology: we call $\forall$ the "universal quantifier." So the above pattern of symbols can be read: "for all $\theta$ in $\mathbb{R}$, it holds that $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$."

Often, we simply use words instead of symbols, so $$\mathop{\forall}_{x:X}[\mbox{blah blah}]$$ becomes: "for all $x$ of type $X$, blah blah."

Now please Google the words "function" and "predicate" if you're unfamiliar with these terms, because here comes the tricky part.

If you think about it, you'll see that *if* we're given a function $f : Y \leftarrow X$ and a predicate $P$ on $Y$, *then* from the statement $$\mathop{\forall}_{y:Y} P(y),$$ we can deduce $$\mathop{\forall}_{x:X} P(f(x)).$$ This explains how we got from $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$ to $\sin^2(\theta+1)+\cos^2(\theta+1) = 1.$ What's really going on is the following. We know that:

$$\mathop{\forall}_{\theta:\mathbb{R}}(\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2\theta = 1).$$

Now write $P(\theta)$ as shorthand for $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$. So we know that $$\mathop{\forall}_{\theta:\mathbb{R}}P(\theta)$$

Now define a function $f : \mathbb{R} \leftarrow \mathbb{R}$ as follows:

$$f(\theta) = \theta+1$$

Then we can deduce $$\mathop{\forall}_{\theta:\mathbb{R}}P(f(\theta)).$$

That is:

$$\mathop{\forall}_{\theta:\mathbb{R}}P(\theta+1).$$

That is:

$$\mathop{\forall}_{\theta:\mathbb{R}}(\sin^2 (\theta+1) + \cos^2(\theta+1) = 1).$$

which is what we were trying to show.

This explains why this pattern of reasoning works here, and not with $3x=2$. The notation $3x=2$ isn't shorthand for $$\mathop{\forall}_{x:\mathbb{R}}(3x=2),$$ since that would simply be *false*.

In summary, if we want our notation to make clear what the "rules of the game" are, then its a good idea to include the symbol $\forall$ or the phrase "for all" in our mathematical writing.

**Returning to your original question.**

Suppose you want to emphasize that the pattern of symbols $$\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2\theta = 1$$ is really a shorthand for the more correct statement $$\mathop{\forall}_{\theta:\mathbb{R}}(\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2\theta = 1).$$

Then, if you want, you can write $$\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2\theta \equiv 1$$ to emphasize this.

**Example.**

Let me finish by illustrating how and when to use $=$ versus $\equiv$, in line with recommendation (2).

> **Proposition.** $1+\tan^2x \equiv \sec^2x$ over the real numbers.

*Proof.* Let $x$ denote a fixed but arbitrary real number. Then the following are equivalent.

1. $1+\tan^2x = \sec^2x$
2. $1+\sin^2 x / \cos^2 x = 1/\cos^2 x$
3. $\cos^2x+\sin^2 x = 1$
4. TRUE

Hence $1+\tan^2x \equiv \sec^2x$ over the real numbers. This completes the proof.

Comment: This is an enjoyable read. :-)

Comment: Good read. Not sure if it matches the level of the question, but a very good read nonetheless!

Comment: @zahbaz, thanks. I think a better answer would be longer, and would give an intuitive explanation of the basics of functions and predicates, thereby "reducing" the level of the answer. But I just run out of steam sometimes...

Comment: Why do you use *types*? Why not $\forall_{\theta\in \mathbb{R}} P(\theta)$? Or, if you insist on using types, wouldn't the Pi-type $\prod_{\theta\colon\mathbb{R}}P(\theta)$ be the standard way to encode universal quantification? You are also the first person I've ever seen who consistently writes $f: Y\leftarrow X$ instead of $f: X\to Y$. That's a lot of unconventional notation for an answer that explains some notational conventions ;)

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, it *is* a lot of unconventional notation, I'll give you that. Regarding types: I don't really know what they are, I don't understand how they're different to sets, they don't feature in how I think about maths. **However,** the way I like to think about set theory is that each variable $x$ is associated with a unique set, called the type of $x$. This is the set that $x$ varies over. So I guess I write $x:X$ to emphasize that I'm taking this viewpoint. Check out the nLab pages about material set theory and structural set theory; the latter is the perspective that I'm coming from.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, regarding your second comment, I write $f : Y \leftarrow X$ to make the composition law easier: $$\frac{g:Z \leftarrow Y \qquad f : Y \leftarrow X}{g \circ f : Z \leftarrow X}$$ I've had some basic exposure to cognitive psychology as part of my education, and I guess the idea that we should be using notation that minimizes the amount of cognitive load on the brain really made an impression on me.

Comment: Ah, structural set theory... Yes, I've heard of that, I think I must have seen those nLab articles already. I don't quite understand where *exactly* the differences between ZFC and the structural set theory are, and how it all relates to Martin-Lof Type Theories, but I think that one should warn the reader if one does not use the standard ZFC. Regarding your answer to my second comment: good point! However, it probably would be easier to replace $g\circ f$ by $f ; g$, and switch to the method-call notation $x.f$ instead of $f(x)$. This would truly allow us to write math from left to right ;D

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, I mean, ZFC is just so weird and quirky and strange, I don't really accept that it's the "standard" foundation for mathematics in any meaningful sense. And sure, it is often claimed that ZFC is "standard," but the material set theory approach is just *soooo* far from how I view things, I find it impossible to take these sorts of claims altogether seriously.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, regarding $g \circ f$ versus $f;g$, I toyed quite a bit with the latter when I was younger, but ended up deciding that $g \circ f$ was the superior notation. Otherwise, syntax trees end up going "root-last" rather than "root-first", we end up with quantifiers at the *end* of expressions, and things just end up looking really weird and unfamiliar: $$\frac{d}{dx} x^2 \;\;\mbox { becomes }\;\;x^2 \frac{d}{xd}$$ etc.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are working on some foundational stuff where you have to treat judgemental and propositional equality differently, 
I think it's mostly matter of taste, and depends on the conventions used in your lecture / in the book that you are reading.

I would read the triple bar here as "equal by definition", whereas "=" would indicate that some identity has been used. So, the first triple bar is correct (I assume that the $\tan$ function has been defined by $\tan(x) :\equiv \sin(x)/\cos(x)$). The usage of the second triple bar is not correct, because you neither use $\sin$ and $\cos$ to define $1$ (the definition $1 :\equiv \sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x)$ is completely nonsensical), nor the other way round (the definition $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) :\equiv 1$ would be even more absurd). The last usage of $\equiv$ is again correct, because $\sec(x) :\equiv 1/\cos(x)$ by definition.

I would rather use $a \overset{\textrm{def}}= b$ if I wanted to emphasize that the two expressions on both sides are equal by definition. Or just leave all the confusing decorative elements out, and use only simple "="-equality signs.

See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_bar

Answer (score 2):

While uses of the triple bar "$\equiv$" are varied, it does have a meaning in connection with distinguishing identities (equations that hold for all unknowns) versus "contingent" equalities (equations that hold for selected values of unknowns).

If an equation has no unknowns, there is no distinction to be drawn.  But consider this well-known identity:

$$ \sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta \equiv 1 \tag{1}$$

which holds for all angles $\theta$.

Equation (1) might be useful in solving for a particular value of $\theta$, but some additional information would need to be supplied, like this "contingent" equality:

$$ \cos 2 \theta = 1/2 \tag{2}$$

The latter equation is not true of all angles, but only for some.  Hence we do not consider (2) to be an *identity* (meaning "identically true").

Answer (score 0):

The triple bar symbol is used to show identity... Here's one way to consider its usage:

$A \equiv B\quad$ The triple bar implies that $A$ and $B$ are identically the same, all the time, for whatever values that may be inputted to them in the specified domain. For example, $1 \equiv 1$. No matter what happens, those two are identical!

$A = B\quad$ On the other hand, using the equals sign states that the left hand side and right hand side are balanced, for at least some value. For example $1=x$ for well, only one value of $x$, which is $x=1$. If no value can be found to ensure equality, then the statement is false.

In practice, outside a few realms of mathematics, you won't often come across a *need* to use the triple bar $\equiv$ at all. A lot of individuals tend to use $\equiv$ mostly for *emphasis* when one reaches some notable identity in a proof. The typical equals sign should suffice in nearly all of your cases.

---

Also, some individuals have noted that the triple bar is used to symbolize  *definitions*. This is true. You might encounter either $\equiv$ or $:=$ or even some other notations to represent a definition. And well, definitions are identical to themselves, so for most intents and purposes, you may as well read $\equiv$ as *identical*.