# When are equations considered equivalent?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology

I know of this definition: "equivalent equations - equations that have the same set of solutions". Is that all, or do we need to add something about the domain?  If two equations have the same solution but different domain, can we say that these equations are equivalent?

For example:

1. $(x-2)(x^2+1)=0$

   Domain: $\mathbb R$

   $x_0=2$
2. $\sqrt{x-2}=0$

   Domain: $[2,\infty)$

   $x_0=2$

Both equations have the same solution $x_0=2;$ however, for $x = -10$, the second equation doesn't exist while the first equation is logical false.

Comment: You can say they are equal for $x=2$

Comment: From a "logical point of view" an equation is an open formula $\phi(x)$ that define a set: the set of "solutions" : $\{ x \mid \phi(x) \}$ (possibly : $\emptyset$).

Comment: Thus, we may say that two equations are "equivalent" if they define the same "solution set".

Answer (score 1):

1. The statements \begin{align}∀x{\in}\mathbb
       R\:\:\Big((x-2)(x^2+1)=0\iff
       x=2\Big)\\∀x{\in}[2,\infty)\:\:\Big((x-2)(x^2+1)=0\iff\sqrt{x-2}=0\Big)\tag0\end{align}
   are both true, and the [conditional
   equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4254850/21813)
   $$(x-2)(x^2+1)=0\tag1$$ and $$\sqrt{x-2}=0\tag2$$ are equivalent to
   each other **on the interval** $\mathbf{[2,\infty)}.$
2. Technically, equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ and the biconditional
   \begin{align}(x-2)(x^2+1)=0\longleftrightarrow\sqrt{x-2}=0\end{align}
   do not have definite truth values, so are
   [predicates](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4231999/21813) rather
   than statements.
3. In the context of $\mathbb R,$ since the above biconditional is
   well-formed only on $[2,\infty),$ the equivalence of equations $(1)$
   and $(2)$ is tacitly understood as being quantified on that
   interval.

   In other words, if the domain of discourse hasn't been specified, then $$(x-2)(x^2+1)=0\iff\sqrt{x-2}=0$$ should be considered an abridgement of statement $(0).$

Answer (score 0):

"The same set of solutions" says it all.

$$(x-2)(x^2+1)=0\iff x=2$$

and

$$\sqrt{x-2}=0\iff x=2,$$

that's it.

The extent of the domain is implicit in the definition, as a solution is valid only if it lies in the domain.

---

The situation would be different if you had additional restrictions on the domain, like if you had to solve $f(x)=0$, where

$$f(x):[10,\infty)\to\mathbb R:x\to(x-2)(x^2+1)$$ (no solution).

Comment: You seem to be saying that a specification of domain is implicit in the equations, as only $x$ that are solutions will be considered.  But the Question itself provides different domains for the two equations, and if the first (polynomial) equation were considered on the domain of complex numbers, there would be additional solutions.  So not only additional *restrictions* can change the picture, enlargements or other changes to the domain affect "equivalence" of equations.