# What is the correct meaning of term "formula"?

Tags: terminology

What is the correct meaning of term "formula"?

My teacher says that a formula is valid for all values of variables we plug in. Is it true that we can say formula is valid for all defined values of variable we plug in? I got this doubt when he told me the "formula"

$$(\tan(x))^2(\sin(x))^2 = (\tan(x))^2 - (\sin(x))^2\,.$$

Is it correct to say it a formula? Or is this just two functions equal to each other for the values of $x$ for which they are defined?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you're describing an "identity": two different looking expressions that are actually identical for all inputs. A "formula" is a recipe for computing some desired quantity, such as the formula for the area of a circle or the quadratic formula.

Comment: My answer is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4254850/21813).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terms "formula" and "equation" can be thought of as synonyms, but the word "formula" has a specific [connotation](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/connotation) to it. I think of a formula as more of a *recipe* for a specific output. The formula *for distance* is the equation $d = rt$, which is a recipe for calculating the distance something travels $d$ given its rate of travel $r$ and duration of travel $t$ as ingredients.

I wouldn't describe what the equation you wrote as a "formula".

Comment: sir how could you describe the equation i write, simply an equation or something like identity

Comment: @lalittolani Yeah I like the word "identity" for it since that equation is manifestly true for any argument $x$. That's as opposed to an equation like $y = 3x+4$ that is either only true for certain pairs $(x,y)$, or that you must declare to be true and intrinsically restrict your attention to those same $(x,y)$ anyways.

Comment: can an identity have a set of values of   variable such that it is defined for values of variable which are  part of that set only

Comment: @lalittolani I mean, yeah? Your equation is only an "identity" on the $x$ that are in the domain of $\tan$ and $\sin$. But to call something an "identity" you probably want it to hold true on the entire maximum (implied) domain of inputs like this. It would be silly to say something "*the equation $x^2=9$ is an identity for $x$ in the set $\{-3,3\}$*. Not much of an "identity" that would be.

Answer (score 1):

A formula can be seen as an expression that returns a value given $n$ number of parameters. An example is $$A=S^2$$ This "formula" gives the area of a square with side length $S$. On the other hand, a function is a special type of relationship between two sets called domain and codomain: each element in the domain is mapped to one and only one element in the codomain. Now, the example you were given is usually called a trigonometric identity, you can look at it as equality between two formulas, it is not a formula itself.